# Scroll becomes slow when page becomes huge

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I have infinite scroll on my website. After a while, when the page keeps loading things and becomes huge(height > 50000px) the scroll becomes extremely laggy and slow.
The page consists of mostly images and videos(html5 and youtube videos in iframes).

The jquery overall remains fast but the jquery slide events also becomes slow.

What can i do to make it faster? Specially the scroll.

Comment: What can you do to make it faster? Don't do infinite scrolling. It's terrible for UX, anyways.

Comment: Wow... Infinite scroll with lots of images and videos?? How come it becomes slow???? Images and videos are so light!!

Comment: and your content(video/images) is it in a specific element with a unique class?

Comment: I mean you could delete stuff that's out of the view, but infinite scrolls are a terrible UX choice anyway. You'd be better off ditching it.

Comment: I have a social networking websites where there are endless posts that keep coming... what can i do other than infinite scroll?

Comment: You need to start removing old content...

Comment: but if i do that, the user will lose content..

Comment: Reload it when they scroll back up

Comment: but that would spoil UX too

Comment: You could always just paginate it based on 24-hour blocks if a content limit is exceeded. When your average user starts getting better machines you can raise the limit.

Answer (score 1):

This [article about handling the ngRepeat directive in AngularJS](http://blog.stackfull.com/2013/02/angularjs-virtual-scrolling-part-1/) do tackle a "similar" problem. (Not the same thing at all)

**But!**, from your question I believe you're doing it wrong. You should paginate or something else. Your users won't loose content. Everything is in your "database", right? Right?

It really seems you're looking for a solution for what isn't you real problem. Please reconsider. Reevaluate your circumstances. Do study other solutions and approaches. Go with something else.

Comment: but most of the social networking websites use a similar approach.. and their scroll does not lag so much